# Port numbers when Running Service

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I want to just default to port 80.  When I right-click my WCF service in Visual Studio and select View in Browser, it somehow auto selects a port for me:

```
http://localhost:55129/Events.svc?wsdl
```

I want it to just be `http://localhost/Events.svc?wsdl`

Do I need to setup this service in IIS somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on project, go to properties .

select the web tab, click on "Use visual studio Development server"

Click on specify port and enter 80.

Please confirm that port 80 is not in use by other apps.

Comment: thanks.  So we don't need to ever setup a WCF service in IIS?  I like working in IIS...

Comment: interesting, I haven't setup an WCF service before.  It gives you the same Web tab as a Web Project.

Comment: instead of selecting "Use visual studio Development server", select "Use local IIS Web server". In project url: http://localhost:80/. You also need to setup the application from IIS

Comment: oh hell no, I'd never use cassini.  I actually don't like IIS Express, I like straight IIS in fact.  Yea I know how to set it up in IIS.  Right now it was set to IIS Express which I have never used.  I always just used IIS so not sure why anyone would want some IIS Express

Comment: But you can uncheck IIS express if you don't want to use it